# serializer.save is not update in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest frame work.
I made a bulk create function, However, it is created only once, and when executed twice, you get an error saying that the code column already exists. just it create works.
This is my code

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Stock


class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    listedDate = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d",input_formats=['%Y%m%d'])

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = '__all__'
```

model

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    cnt = models.BigIntegerField()
    construction = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    listedDate = models.DateTimeField()
    lastPrice = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'stock'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets, status

from util import setEnvironment
from . import models, serializers


class StockViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StockSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        stock_data = request.data.get("data")
        auth = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION')       
        api_key = setEnvironment.get_secret("API_AUTH_KEY")
        if auth != api_key:  
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=stock_data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        print(serializer.data)  
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

I think if you call perform_create in viewsets.py, you need to save or update it.
As a result, i get an error saying that the same code value exists.

Why doesn't the update automatically work even though I have a primary key in db?

Added 2021-01-22

My json data

```
{
    "data": [
           {
            "code": "50F02511",
            "name": "\uC2E0\uD55CF025\uC0BC\uC131\uC804\uC790\uCF5C",
            "cnt": 14000001,
            "construction": "\uC815\uC0C1",
            "listedDate": "20201228",
            "lastPrice": "00000135",
            "state": "\uC99D\uAC70\uAE08100%"
        },
        {
            "code": "50F02611",
            "name": "\uC2E0\uD55CF026\uC0BC\uC131\uC804\uC790\uCF5C",
            "cnt": 13000000,
            "construction": "\uC815\uC0C1",
            "listedDate": "20201228",
            "lastPrice": "00000000",
            "state": "\uC99D\uAC70\uAE08100%"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `request.data` instead you are passing the `data` of `request.data`. So update the code like this:

```
stock_data = request.data
```

BTW, I think you are over doing the override of default create method. To be honest, you do not need to change anything here. You can add a [custom permission class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) in here, like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsAuthorized(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        auth = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION')       
        api_key = setEnvironment.get_secret("API_AUTH_KEY")
        return auth == api_key

class StockViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StockSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthorized]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I think it's good to separate the verification code.
but The reason I used request.data.get("data") is because I have a value in json formatted data like below.
```
{
  data: [
          ...value...
   ]
}
```

Comment: Currently, it is created, but once created, it is not updated.
Because it already exists, the error code comes out like this
stock with this code already exists.